# Copying & pasting range with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I think I have some fundamental misunderstanding about how getRange or setValue works.

I want to copy the last row of data, columns 1-5, and paste them into another spreadsheet in the first row, columns 1-5.

When I run my script, it sets the value of the last row, first column into the first row and in all 5 columns.

So if I have Mon, Tues, Wed, Thur, Fri in the source data, then what is pasted into the second spreadsheet I get Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon, Mon.

Thanks

```
    function myFunction() {
// Last Row
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()

// Assign last row from source data to variable
  var lastRowSourceData = ss.getRange(lastRow,1,1,5).getValue()


// Paste form values into master log 
  var makeEntryHere = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kBfBHnNFyqC-ACyHs6Q09IYj2TzF3RWBwp-yvYtxd34').getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange(1,1,1,5);
  makeEntryHere.setValue(lastRowSourceData);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is just fine, correct `.getValue()` to `.getValues()` and `.setValue()` to `.setValues()` respectively and it should work:

```
function myFunction() {
// Last Row
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

// Assign last row from source data to variable
var lastRowSourceData = ss.getRange(lastRow,1,1,5).getValues();


// Paste form values into master log 
var makeEntryHere = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kBfBHnNFyqCACyHs6Q09IYj2TzF3RWBwp-yvYtxd34').getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange(1,1,1,5);
makeEntryHere.setValues(lastRowSourceData);
}
```